# How to design a table using variable number of attributes?

Tags: database-design

Imagine a system that stores personal details that allow users to store any number of phone numbers including none. How would this be stored in a table if each phone number is under an attribute?

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please read & act on How to Ask & the downvote arrow mouseover text. Time to read a textbook on information modeling, the relational model & database design. (Nb--A manual for a design tool, api or language to record designs is not a manual/tutorial on design.) If you have a textbook, what does it suggest & how is your case a problem & not already in it as an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. A table in a database can't have a variable number of columns.

What you do in situations like this is store the users in one table, and the phone number in another table, linked to the users table via a foreign key constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    firstName varchar(10),
    -- rest of the users details goes here
);

CREATE TABLE PhoneNumbers
(
    userId FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Users(Id),
    PhoneNumber varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    Description varchar(20) -- Home, Mobile, Office etc'
)
```

This way, each user can have 0, 1 or multiple phone numbers.